# The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm curently devlopping a VBA Macro that uses an ADODB connection to search data from an other excel document. It's working but sometimes, when i restart my computer or close and reopen the file, i have an error while running the Macro: "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object Details$" even if i didn't changed anything. To correct this error, the only way that i found is recreate a file in the same repository, copy and paste my macro and it's working. Here's the code i'm using:

```
With Conn
.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
 & FichierCarto & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
.Open
End With

Set rsT = New ADODB.Recordset

rSQL1 = "SELECT [Service à délivrer], [Service environnement], [Type de CI], [Cout mensuel], [UO], [CI] FROM [Details$] WHERE [Service environnement]='" & Recherche & "' AND [Type de CI] <> null"
```

Do someone sees something that could trigger this error? i'm using this file on a daily basis but i spend too much time searching the source of this error or recreating files.

Comment: You should only be using one provider string. What format is the workbook?

Comment: Does FichierCarto  hold the full path to the excel workbook? Is it on a networkshare that isn't being reconnected under the same drive letter?

Comment: The workbook is a .xlsx file

Comment: FichierCarto is the name of the file that i use

Comment: If it's only the filename then it will only work if the folder it is stored in is the current folder - I would extend it to the full path

Comment: The files are in the same folder and the connection to the file worked randomly. I added the full path and it's workng, thanks for your help